# Localization with string.Format

Tags: c#, uwp

Currently I am mostly doing the localization by putting key-value pairs into a `Resources.resw` file. So I wonder about how I should localize strings that need formatting or say strings with different grammar orders in different languages. It might be easier to understand what I mean with the examples below.

For example, just as this part in the [official document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/windows/uwp/design/globalizing/prepare-your-app-for-localization#ensure-the-correct-parameter-order-when-formatting-strings) for localization suggests, one language can have the date format of

```
string.Format("Every {0} {1}", monthName, dayNumber);
```

while the other uses

```
string.Format("Every {1} {0}", monthName, dayNumber);
```

In this situation, what is the best way to localize such a string?

Things/Grammars can be way more complicated than this example. The suggestion in the [official document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/windows/uwp/design/globalizing/prepare-your-app-for-localization#consider-factoring-your-strings-into-sentences) doesn't look good to me because a date can be unpredictable. Or may be you can enumerate the date, but that requires a lot of work. Or let's say we have a string that takes user input, like

```
 string.Format("Do you want to delete {name}?", name);
```

In another language it might have this grammar order

```
string.Format("You want to delete {name} do?", name);
```

It is impossible to localize the whole sentence as the example suggests in the document.

The only way of avoiding situation that I can think of is not to put user input....

Comment: I really don't understand your problem. Why can't you use the string `Do you want to delete {0}?` for English and `Möchten Sie {0} entfernen?` for German?

Comment: @Dirk I didn't reject that option. I am mostly doing the localization in a `Resources.resw` file. I just wonder if this problem can still be solved using that, or I have to do it in csharp code.

Comment: If you want a better way to signal which kind of parameter goes in which place, you will have to roll your own solution. You can make it as simple (use string.format as-is) or as complex (handle pluralization and ending differences, word replacements depending on parameter values, etc.) as you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way I just found out is to put this key-value pair into the `Resources.resw`:

Key: `RemoveText`

Value: `Do you want to delete {0}?`

After you get the localized string like doing

```
var msg = Localize('RemoveText');
```

Then

```
var result = string.Format(msg, name)
```

can give you the expected result.

Basically, you need to put `{0}` appropriately in every language. The only flaw of this solution is that `{0}` should not be allowed in the user input.

If you still want `{0}` to appear, you can change `{0}` to other strings that you think are too complicated and long for user to type in, for example `'{usersAreVeryUnlikelyToTypeInThisInTheirInputs}'`. And then use

```
msg.replace('{usersAreVeryUnlikelyToTypeInThisInTheirInputs}', name)
```

to get the localized string.

Answer (score 1):

If you have access to the date you could use [The Month ("M", "m") Format Specifier](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/standard-date-and-time-format-strings#MonthDay)

From the documentation:

```
DateTime date1 = new DateTime(2008, 4, 10, 6, 30, 0);
Console.WriteLine(date1.ToString("m", 
                  CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("en-us")));
// Displays April 10                        
Console.WriteLine(date1.ToString("m", 
                  CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("ms-MY")));
// Displays 10 April
```

---

For `string.Format("Do you want to delete {name}?", name);` you can

```
$"Do you want to delete the following user? '{name}'";
```

Comment: Using interpolated strings in `string.Format` without any format parameter look weird. Just remove `string.Format` The problem is that interpolated strings in resources - needed to be localizable - are not supported.

Comment: The last will throw an exception if name contains curly braces, because the if someone inputs his name as {0} string.Format will throw because it would expect an argument 0. So the last one is not an option.

Comment: @ckuri If you claim `var name = "{ckuri}";Console.WriteLine($"Do you want to delete the following user? '{name}'");` will throw, then you're wrong.

Comment: No, but it will if your name is `{0}`.

Comment: No, I don't think it would. Why would it?

Comment: `var name = "{ckuri}"; Console.WriteLine(string.Format($"User {name}"));` will throw a FormatException (see  https://dotnetfiddle.net/wsbeMH).

Comment: @ckuri it only throws because you use `String.Format`. If you omit that it works.

Comment: @Dirk Before the answer was edited it read `string.Format($"Do you … '{name}'"))`.

Comment: @ckuri `string.Format` was gone before you added comment :)

Comment: I have also thought about the last option but I am just expecting that there might be a better way...Let me wait for a while and see if there is a better answer.

Comment: There is no better way built into the runtime or C#. You will have to roll your own, or accept what is there.