# How to localize a string in unity where different languages may have different grammars

Tags: c#, string, unity-game-engine, translation, string-concatenation

I'm translating a Unity game and some of the lines go like

> Unlock at XXXX

where "XXXX" is replaced at runtime by an arbitrary substring. Easy enough to replace the wildcards, but to translate the quote, I can't simply concatenate a + b, as some languages will have the value before or inside the string. I figured I needed to, effectively, de-replace it, ie isolate and keep the substring and translate whatever's around it.

Problem is that while I can easily do the second part, I can't think of any avenues for the first. I know to get the character index of what I'm looking for, but the value takes up an arbitrary number of characters, and I can't use whitespace since some languages don't use it. Can't use digit detection since not all of the values are going to be numbers. I tried asking Google, but I couldn't translate "find whatever replaces a wildcard" into something keyword-searchable.

In short, what I'm looking for is a way to find the "XXXX" (the easy part) and then **find whatever replaces it in the string** (the less-easy part).

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What if you translate the whole string, verbatim, and just make sure the translation also contains XXXX? And then use the translation instead of the original and then do the replacement? Translating the string *after* it has had its replacements done is going to be much more difficult.

Comment: Please post your code, that will give us somewhere to start...

Comment: It's what I tried to do at first, but since Unity gonna Unity, I found I'd have to translate text as it becomes visible.

haven't got any code thus far since I couldn't get anything to stick.

Comment: Surely the XXXX is a variable?? can you not do $"Unlock at {myvar}" where myvar is the translated detail?

Comment: It's what happens, but my translation method only takes the finished text as input. I do suppose I can make another method that does take the value as a secondary argument, so I'll try that.

Comment: This seems like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/405359). You should re-engineer your code so that your translation method doesn't only take the finished text.

Comment: Consider having it take a language identifier (such as an enum or a string with an iso locale code), an identifier for the statement (such as `1` for any language's "Unlock at XXXX") and a list of objects to "plug in" to translate according to that language and to plug into the slots of that statement. 
 See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58445615/1092820) and [here](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/a/694/121653) especially the "don't concatenate strings in code" part

Answer (score 1):

I eventually found a workaround, thanks to everybody's kind advice. I stored the substring and referred to it in a special translation method that does take in a value. Thanks for your kind help, everybody.

```
public static string TranslateWithValue (string text, string value, int language) {
    string sauce = text.Replace (value, "XXXX");
    sauce = Translate (sauce, language);
    sauce = sauce.Replace ("XXXX", value);
    return sauce;
}
```

Comment: you should rather use a list or a dictionary of values instead of a single string.

Comment: I gather from your answer that the keyword in the text is **not** `XXXX` as you portrayed in the question? Otherwise, why do you need to replace first at all?

Comment: For what it's worth, it is in fact "XXXX." I use a string file, so it could effectively be anything.

Answer (score 0):

Usually, I use string.Format in such cases. In your case, I'd declare 2 localizeable strings:

`string unlockFormat = "Unlock at {0}";
string unlockValue = "next level";`

When you need the unlock condition displayed, you can combine the strings like that:

`string unlockCondition = string.Format(unlockFormat, unlockValue);`

which will produce the string "Unlock at next level".

Both unlockFormat and unlockValue can be translated, and the translator can move {0} wherever needed.